# Get the n previous elements of a list for all/some elements

Tags: python

I have a long list of integers and a subset of indexes that I want to get the last n elements (n = 1,2,3,4,...) for every index.
The code so far.

```
data = range(0, 20);
indexes = [8, 9, 10, 11];  
n = 4; #A parameter

for i in indexes:    
    t = [];
    for j in range(1, n+1):
       t.append(data[i-j]);
    print t;
```

This should print:

```
[4,5,6,7]
[5,6,7,8]
[6.7.8.9]
[7,8,9,10]
```

How can i use list comprehension to get rid of the inner loop?
I tried something like:

```
d[-n : i]
```

but it returns an empty array.

Comment: Can you support your question with sample input and expected output ?

Comment: What is variable `d` ?

Comment: d is the first letter of data! Typo. sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the catch is in list slicing and not in list comprehension, the list slicing syntax looks like: `lst[start_index : end_index]`.

Also another thing to keep in mind is to prevent `start_index < 0`, for that we can use `max`.

Yes you may use list comprehension as:

```
lst = range(20)
indices = [3, 7, 15]

n = 4

sub_lists = [lst[max(0, i-n):i] for i in indices]

print sub_lists
# [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [11, 12, 13, 14]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The list compression for inner loop will be

```
t = [d[i - n] for i in range(1, n + 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your answers.
Here is my go, with a little bit of help from ZdaR:

```
data = range(0, 20);
indexes = [2, 3, 4];
n = 4; #A parameter

for i in indexes:
    t = data[:i][max(-i, -n):];
    print t;
```

The outer loop is required in my case, but if it wasn't it will be something similar to ZdaR.

```
t = [data[:i][max(-i, -n):] for i in indexes];
```